# common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@5e559877 while sending a message from apex class

Tags: apex-email-service

I'm trying to send an email from the apex class using the javascript. Im not getting any emails. I found **common.apex.runtime.impl.ScalarList@5e559877** which i have never seen before. Please find the code used below and help me in this issue.

```
global class EmailHelper
{ 

    public string toAddress{get;set;}
    public string message{get;set;}
    public list<Account> acclist = new list<account>();
    webservice static void patientInitials(ID AccID)
    {
        system.debug('**Account ID**'+AccID);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage Email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        list<Account> acclist = [select id,name,personEmail from account where id=:AccID];
        String[] sendingTo= new List<String>();
        for(Account acc:acclist)
        {
            sendingTo.add(acc.personemail);
        }
        system.debug('***ToAddr**'+sendingTo );
        Email.setToAddresses(sendingTo);
        String subject ='Patient Initials';
        Email.setSubject(subject);
        Email.setPlainTextBody('Dear Patient\n\nPlease find the list of patient initials requested\n\nThanks and Regards,\nAlexion Team');        
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {Email});
        system.debug('****'+r);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not an error message, just some sort of default toString implementation (class-name@memory-address) syntax. While unusual, it does not indicate an error. You'll need to do more debugging.

Comment: Is Email Deliverability turned on? What specifically do you see in your logs? Are any exceptions thrown? What line produces the debug message you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the response @DavidReed....The email deliverability is ON and is set to 'ALL EMAIL'. The debug message that Im seeing is being produced at  'Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {Email});'. 

Please let me know your concerns regarding the same.

Comment: Thanks for the response @sfdcfox... Im unable to find where exactly did my syntax thing went wrong. Could you please help me out of this